# What is the best practice of bulk delete without cascading in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to load datas from a table by some criterias and then insert them into history table. After that i want to delete the data from the first table. It is just like moving data from one table to another.

Here is my code:

```
    long started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<SentNtf> sentNtfListToBackup = sentNtfDAO.getNtfListToBackup();

    long ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " getNtfListToBackup tooks " + duration + " ms.");

    if(sentNtfListToBackup == null || sentNtfListToBackup.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }   

    started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    HashMap<Integer, NotificationHistory> ntfs = new HashMap<Integer, NotificationHistory>();
    for(SentNtf sentNtf : sentNtfListToBackup){
        NotificationHistory nh = createNotificationHistory(sentNtf.getNotification());
        ntfs.put(nh.getRid(), nh);
    }

    ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " loading NotificationHistory to memory tooks " + duration + " ms.");

    started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    insertObjects(new ArrayList<Object>(ntfs.values()));

    ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " inserting NotificationHistory to db tooks " + duration + " ms.");


    started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(SentNtf sentNtf : sentNtfListToBackup){
        SentNtfHistory snh = createSentNtfHistory(sentNtf, ntfs.get(sentNtf.getNotification().getRid()));
        list.add(snh);
    }

    ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " loading SentNtfHistory to memory tooks " + duration + " ms.");

    started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    insertObjects(list);

    ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " inserting SentNtfHistory to db tooks " + duration + " ms.");

    started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    deleteSentNtfs(sentNtfListToBackup);

    ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " deleting SentNtfHistory from db tooks " + duration + " ms.");

    started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    deleteNtfs(sentNtfListToBackup);

    ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
    duration = ended - started;
    logger.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " deleting NtfHistory from db tooks " + duration + " ms.");
```

And here is the log :

```
getNtfListToBackup tooks 14962 ms.
loading NotificationHistory to memory tooks 109 ms.
inserting NotificationHistory to db tooks 47868 ms.
loading SentNtfHistory to memory tooks 404 ms.
inserting SentNtfHistory to db tooks 75916 ms.
deleting SentNtfHistory from db tooks 1081012 ms.
deleting NtfHistory from db tooks 1114347 ms.
```

As you can see although inserting 150K entities to destination tables tooks 2 minutes, deleting them from source tables tooks 36.5 minutes!!!

I am deleting the entities like this :

```
String hql = "delete from " + tableName + " f where f." + idName + " in (:ids)";
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameterList("ids", ids).executeUpdate();
```

So what will be the best approach for this issue?

Thanks in advance.